# iOS 7 - How to eliminate white area on top of screenshot

Tags: ios7, screenshot

Using Xcode 5.1 and target 7.1 or 6.1 I am capturing a screenshot and posting it for an e-mail. The image in the e-mail has an unwanted white area on top. I am using the following code:

```
CGSize mySize;
mySize.width = 320;
mySize.height = 480;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( mySize, YES, 0.0);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
NSData *newPNG=UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:newPNG, nil] applicationActivities:nil];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypePrint];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I would like to eliminate the excessive white space on top of the obtained screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you setting the height (and width) absolutely? Shouldn't you be using the height and width _of the screen_? (Or even better, of `self.view.layer`?)

Comment: By the way, you are forgetting to say `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()`. That is very bad.

Comment: Matt: I am trying to reduce the size of the screenshot. That is the reason for the 320 x 480. Thanks for the suggestion to include the UIGraphicsEndImageContext(). Hey matt, guess I am just a very bad kind of guy.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that will "reduce the size of the screenshot".

Comment: Matt: I guess what I am attempting is to programmatically crop a screen shot.